# can't find windows service template for VS 2010 express

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-services

i just installed Visual basic 2010 Express , it works fine  , but i couldn't find the `Windows Service Template` , i'm using `.NET 4.0` i guess i don't have any experience working with visual studio
*NOTICE* the online Templates link to the left doesn't show any thing useful

**QUESTION** How can i get or install the `Windows Service` to Visual studio 2010 Express ,

Thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Windows Service** template is not available for Visual Studio Express Editions

Look at this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms236405%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). It is for C# but I think that it is the same for VB.NET

Comment: so what is the best way of getting this template